# Can my digicom router be repaired?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a DIGICOM Router that has been dead,the most probable cause i have known so far is due to lightining strike(as my neighbours too had dead routers after the same night). Is there any way i can fix the problem.When i power on the router,it switches on,then ADSL signalling LED keeps on blinking for a while but the Internet signalling LED does not glow.Can someone contribute to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you connect to the router home page?

Comment: You have to confirm if some other router works and yours does not.  We can't answer this question until you can tell us your internet is actually suppose to be working.

Comment: Ya,I tried a new router and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If other neighbours are also affected, the fault *could* be at the exchange and not with the router; however, if there is no fault at the exchange (and this can be tested with a spare/new router), then the faulty router should be destined for recycling, as it has no user-serviceable parts.